# Why does my maze solver not work?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, maze

I'm trying to write a program that solves a specific inputted maze recursively and outputs it's position in the maze after each move.

Whenever I try and run my code, it immediately crashes and I get a "maze.exe has stopped working" error.

Why isn't my code working?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
const int MazeHeight = 12;
const int MazeWidth = 16;

char Maze[MazeHeight][MazeWidth + 1] =
{
    {'S','.','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
    {'#','#','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','#','#','.'},
    {'.','.','.','.','.','#','.','#','.','.','.','#','.','#','#','.'},
    {'.','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','.','.','.','#','.','#','#','.'},
    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','.','#','#','#','.','#','#','.'},
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','#','#','#','#','#','.'},
    {'.','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','.'},
    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','#','#','.','#','#','#','#','#'},
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','.'},
    {'G','#','#','#','#','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
};



const char Wall = '#';
const char Free = '.';
const char Start = 'S';
const char End = 'G';

int solve(int X = 0, int Y = 0)
{
    while(Maze[Y][X] != End){

    if (Maze[Y][X] == End)
    {
        cout << X << Y << endl;
    }   

    else if (X > 0 && Maze[Y][X - 1] == Free && solve(X - 1, Y))
    {
        cout << X << Y << endl;
    }
    else if (X < MazeWidth && Maze[Y][X + 1] == Free && solve(X + 1, Y))
    {
        cout << X << Y << endl;
    }
    else if (Y > 0 && Maze[Y - 1][X] == Free && solve(X, Y - 1))
    {
        cout << X << Y << endl;
    }
    else if(Y < MazeHeight && Maze[Y + 1][X] == Free && solve(X, Y + 1))
    {
        cout << X << Y << endl;
    }

    else Maze[Y][X] = Free;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    // how do i call from here?
}
```

Comment: "`int main(int X = 0, int Y = 0)`" -- Oh wow. Does your compiler not warn you about that?

Comment: No, everything compiles 100% with no errors.

Comment: Can you hook up a debugger and get a stack trace of where it is failing?

Comment: You're not allowed to call `main` explicitly inside the code. /thread

Comment: usually main looks more like this:  int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

Comment: ok.  Where did you read that the `main` function in C++ is declared like that?  Also, it is not legal to call `main` directly.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore: Somewhat better (doesn't use the misleading array-is-really-a-pointer syntax): `int main(int argc, char** argv)`

Comment: `else if (X > 0 && Maze[Y][X - 1] == Free && main(X - 1, Y))`  Can you explain what is being done here?  I mean the `&& main(X - 1, Y)` part of it.

Comment: Basically, all those parts are checking the spaces next to it, in order of right, left, up, then down, and if a space is open, it takes it and prints out the current position. I updated to what I have now.

Comment: @user3006937 - `solve` always returns 0, so all of those `if` statements are `false`.

Comment: What if I make it so it returns X and Y?

Comment: @user3006937 For debug, try adding a cout at the entry of solve.  Perhaps you will recognize the (unexpected) path of the recursion, and help you find the coding error.  FYI - on Linux, the program terminates with a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3):

When `main` is first called the runtime environment passes it arguments, so your default arguments aren't used.  Rename the function and call it from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe a good reason behind this but I'm not sure why you ignore your const int of 16 as max Width and make it 17 instead. Might not solve the problem but that sure looks wrong to me.

Also like a commenter said why initialise X and Y inside main's brackets? Why not just do it inside main. Or as the other poster said, turn that main function into a separate function then call it in a fresh main.